# Optimization under constraints

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I have a question regarding optimization.

I have a matrix x with 3 columns and a certain number of rows (max 200). Each row represents a candidate. The column one contains a score (between 0 and 1) , the column 2 contains the kind of candidate (there are 10 kinds in total labeled from 1 to 10) and the column 3  contains the amount of each candidate. There is one thing to take into consideration: the amount can be NEGATIVE

What I would like to do is to select max 35 elements among these candidates which would maximize the function which sum over their respective score (column 1) under the constraints that there can be a maximum of 10% of each kind computed in the following way: percenteage of kind 1: sum amount of kind 1 divided by sum all amount.

At the end, I would like to have a set of max 35 candidates which satisfy the constraints and optimize the sum of their scores.

Here is a the code I have come up with so far but I am struggling on the 10% constraint as it seems not to be taken into account:

```
rng('default');

clc;
clear;
n = 100;
maxSize =  35;

%%%TOP BASKET
nbCandidates = 100;
score = rand(100,1)/10+0.9;
quantity = rand(100,1)*100000;
type = ceil(rand(100,1)*10)
typeMask = zeros(n,10);

for i=1:10
    typeMask(:,i) = type(:,1) == i;
end

fTop = -score;
intconTop = [1:1:n];

%Write the linear INEQUALITY constraints: 
A = [ones(1,n);bsxfun(@times,typeMask,quantity)'/sum(type.*quantity)];
b = [maxSize;0.1*ones(10,1)];


%Write the linear EQUALITY constraints:
Aeq = [];
beq = [];

%Write the BOUND constraints: 
lb = zeros(n,1);
ub = ones(n,1); % Enforces i1,i2,...in binary

x = intlinprog(fTop,intconTop,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
```

I would be grateful to some advice where I m doing it wrong!

Comment: What do you mean by the 10% rule? **A**: ```sum_amount_kind_x / sum_all_amounts``` or **B**: ```sum_amound_kind_x_selected / sum_all_amounts_selected```. **A** is a simple mixed-integer program. **B** will be incredibly hard (in my opinion as possibly non-convex).

Comment: Here the 10% rules should be understood as follow: the sum_amount_kind_x after the selection is done, which means respecting the other constrains such as max 35 elements should not be bigger than 10% of the sum_all_amounts_selected. So I Believe this falls unfortunately into your B category. Because basically the A part would not make much sense. I want to have after the selection a max of 10% in each category within the selection. Hope this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear program for your model might look something like this:

- `n` is the number of candidates.
- `S[x]` is candidate `x`'s score.
- `A[i][x]` is the amount of candidate `x` for kind `i` (A[i][x] can be positive or negative, like you said).
- `T[i]` is the total amount of all candidates for kind `i`.
- `I[x]` is 1 if element `x` is to be included, and 0 if element `x` is to be excluded.

The function `f` which you want to optimize is a function of `S[x]` and `I[x]`.  You can think of `S` and `I` as `n`-dimensional vectors, so the function you want to optimize is their dot-product.

`f() = DotProduct(I, S)`

This is equivalent to the linear function `I1 * S1 + I2 * S2 + ... + In * Sn`.

We can formulate all of the constraints in this way to get a set of linear functions whose coeffecients are the components in an `n` dimensional vector that we can dot with `I`, the parameters to optimize.

---

For the constraint that we can only take 35 elements at most, let `C1()` be a function which computes the total number of elements.
Then the first constraint can be formalized as `C1() <= 35` and `C1()` is a linear function which can be computed thusly:

Let `j` be an `n` dimensional vector with each component equal to 1: `j = <1,1,...,1>`.

`C1() = DotProduct(I, j)`

So `C1() <= 35` is a linear inequality equivalent to:

`I1 * 1 + I2 * 1 + ... + In * 1 <= 35`
`I1 + I2 + ... + In <= 35`

We need to add a slack variable `x1` here to turn this into and equivalence relation:

`I1 + I2 + ... + In + x1 = 35`

---

For the constraint that we can only take 10% of each kind, we will have a function `C2[i]()` for each kind `i` (you said there are 10 in all).  `C2[i]()` Computes the amount of students taken for kind `i` given the students we have selected:

- `C21() <= .1 * T1`
- `C22() <= .1 * T2`
- `...`
- `C210() <= .1 * T10`

We compute `C2[i]()` like this:
Let `k` be an `n` dimensional vector equal to `<A[i]1, A[i]2, ..., A[i]n>`, each component is the amount of each candidate for kind `i`.
Then `DotProduct(I, k) = I1 * A[i]1 + I2 * A[i]2 + ... + In * A[i]n`, is the total amount we are taking of kind `i` given `I`, the vector which captures what elements we are including.

So `C2[i]() = DotProduct(I, k)`

Now that we know how to compute `C2[i]()`, we need to add a slack variable to turn this into an equality relation:

`C2[i]() + x[i + 1] = .1 * T[i]`

Here `x`'s subscript is `[i + 1]` because `x1` is already used as a slack variable for the previous constraint.

---

In summary, the linear program would look like this (adding 11 slack variables `x1, x2, ..., x11` for each constraint that is an inequality):

```
Let:
V = <I1, I2, ..., In, x1, x2, ..., x11> (variables)

    |S1|
    |S2|
    |. |
    |. |
    |. |
P = |Sn| (parameters of objective function)
    |0 |
    |0 |
    |. |
    |. |
    |. |
    |0 |

    |35    |            
    |.1*T1 |            
C = |.1*T2 | (right-hand sides of constraining equality relations)      
    |...   |            
    |.1*T10|


     |1    |1    |...|1    |1|0|...|0| 
     |A1,1 |A1,2 |...|A1,n |0|1|...|0|
CP = |A2,1 |A2,2 |...|A2,n |0|0|...|0| (parameters of constraint functions)
     |...  |...  |...|...  |0|0|...|0|
     |A10,1|A10,2|...|A10,n|0|0|...|1|

Maximize:
V x P

Subject to:
CP x Transpose(V) = C
```

Hopefully this is clear, sorry for terrible formatting.

Comment: This is not a linear-program. It's a mixed-integer program. I also think that you misinterpreted the 10% rule (but maybe not; i asked in the comments).

Comment: Ah, you're right.  It should be that a given kind can comprise at most 10% of the amount of the elements being select, not that you can only take 10% of the total amount for a kind.  I'll fix my answer

Comment: Maybe it's like that. I would wait for response first before changing your answer. I'm also curious how you would tackle it. I don't think it will be easy.

Comment: I have answer your comments Sasha. Brian, is your answer the already edited one or still the original one?

Comment: Still original, wasn't aware you answered sascha's question

Comment: No worries! but I would be happy to see then the updated answer :) I m trying to write an example in matlaba and see if I can make it run.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the time to change my answer, but I guess you found it helpful anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MIP model can look like:

[image]

Here `i` are the data points and `j` indicates the type. For simplicity I assumed here every type has the same number of data points (i.e. `Amount(i,j)`, `Score(i,j)` are matrices). It is easy to handle the more irregular case by restricting the summations.

The 10% rule is simply applied on the sum of the amounts. I hope that is the correct interpretation. Not sure if this is true if we have negative sums.

Comment: I think I get the point but I am having trouble to write down the constrain on the type, what you call vlimit. In fact totalv  and vj depends on the same variables. How Would you write this in Matlab? I have tried this:                     Write the linear INEQUALITY constraints: 
A = [ones(1,n);bsxfun(@times,sectorTopMask,quantityTop)'];
b = [maxSize;0.1*ones(10,1).*sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,sectorTopMask,quantityTop)',2))];

Comment: This is not so easily written in Matlab as you have to create two large matrices (one for the equality constraints and one for inequality constraints). Each variable is a column in these matrices. That is a pain, and I am afraid it requires a quite some code. [Here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/10/matlab-vs-gams-integer-programming.html) is an example of how difficult that can be compared to other modeling systems.

Comment: could I share my current code with you? Just to see how it looks like because on my side, it seems much simpler that the example you provided me but somehow the 10% constraint are not respected even if the solution is found. I believe then that I have misswritten them somehow.

Comment: Only if it is accompanied by a purchase order.

Comment: Thanks for the help then but I am not planning to buy anything! I will figure it out!